# Serveless offline TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of null

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

So I can deploy my lambda to aws no problem but trying to run it locally

```
serverless invoke local --function hello

TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessKeyId' of null
```

The congig and credentials file look ok./

```
Edit

~/.aws/config
[default]
region = eu-west-1
output = json
~

[default]
aws_access_key_id = A***************
aws_secret_access_key = /p*********************
```

Answer (score 0):

What aws-sdk version are you using in your function? A quick google showed that there was a problem in the aws-sdk that contained the same error message. Make sure you have the latest version.

Also, remember that when you run a function locally, aws-sdk will look for credentials on your local system.

Run `$ ls  ~/.aws` on a mac and `C:\> dir "%UserProfile%\.aws"` on windows to see if you have your credentials files stored locally. See [this guide for](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) more details.

Comment: I am using aws2 - I can deploy it fine, used to work with cli v1 on my old machine. Maybe need to downgrade.

Comment: ok - then the most likely explanation is that aws cant find your credentials. When you run locally, you must provide your credentials to aws-sdk. You dont need to do this when running directly on aws - it handles this for you. The easiest way to provide credentials is to add them to the \.aws folder on your local machine

Comment: if you want to check this is the problem, manually provide credentials in your function and then run locally. If it works then, your know that aws cant find your \.aws credentials